# how to Convert a normal socket to a ssl socket at client end in java?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, ssl

How do I convert a normal client socket connected to a server to a ssl socket on the same port?
I am using java sockets . My client is in android and the server is a uvnc c/c++ server.

After creating the socket. I am using the inputstream of the socket. I want to enable the DSM plugin for the input stream.How do i go ahead or approach? Googling is not of much help!!

How do i go about de-crytping a message at client end(android/java) , which has been encrypted at the server(c++ server) end by DSM plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket, ...)` method.